# CSS3 вёрстка

Tags: css3, вёрстка, веб-программирование

Как осуществить подобное в **css3**? Я пробовал так:

```
background:#F8F8F8;
border-radius:2px;
border:2px solid #EEEEEE;
border: 1px inset #D8D8D8;
```

[image]

У меня не выходят похожие боковые стороны (проблема не в таблице).
Спасибо!

Comment: :D извините.

Comment: а посмотреть в css примера никак? фаербагом или ручками? дайте ссылку на пример.

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery

Comment: Vitalii Maslianok, если здесь не помогут, буду дальше сам пробовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="bubble">
<table class="tree-browser" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
</table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, div, table, tbody, thead, tr, th, td {
    border: 0 none;
    font: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.bubble {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE;
        border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
        padding: 3px;
    }
    .tree-browser {
        border: 1px solid #CACACA;
        border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
    }
    .tree-browser th {
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FAFAFA, #EAEAEA) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
        color: #555555;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 6px 3px;
        text-align: left;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
    }
    .tree-browser td {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F8F8F8;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
        color: #484848;
        padding: 7px 3px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```